# Specify that the return type is a constructor function or class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that augments a class type:

```
export interface TypeClass<A> {
  instance: (constructor: A, methods?: object) => void;
}

export function type<A extends { new (name: string) }>(Class: A): 
TypeClass<A> {
  let name = Class.name;

  let TypeClass = <A & TypeClass<A>>Class;

  TypeClass.instance = () => // impl

  TypeClass.prototype; // typescript recognises type has a prototype

  return TypeClass;
}
```

But when I come to use this function.

```
const MyType = type(class MyClass {});

MyType.prototype; // typescript does not recognise prototype
```

How can I tell typescript that the return type will have a prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your function is correct, the object that will be returned will be `Class` parameter (which is a type) augmented with an `instance` function. Your function returns `TypeClass<A>` which is just the augmentation interface, it should return `A & TypeClass<A>`, meaning the return value will have the shape of `A` and `TypeClass<A>` at the same time:

```
export function type<A extends { new(name: string) }>(Class: A): A & TypeClass<A> {
    let name = Class.name;

    let TypeClass = <A & TypeClass<A>>Class;
    …
    return TypeClass;
}

const MyType = type(class MyClass { });
MyType.prototype; // works
```

Comment: Thank you, that had me baffled for some time.